# jQuery convert image to grayscale?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and really liking it. I'd like to know if there's an effect similar to IE's in which I can convert images to grayscale in the runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think jQuery has a special way to do it, but you can use the `<canvas>` tag. [see tutorial](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html)

Answer (score 9):

Check out pixastic ... it is supposed to work in ...

- Internet Explorer 5.5+
- Opera 9.5+
- Firefox 2+
- WebKit Nightly

http://dph.am/pixastic-docs/docs/actions/desaturate/

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate", {average : false});
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my simple jQuery plugin: [jquery-grayscale](https://github.com/josefrichter/jquery-grayscale)

You run it like:

```
$('img').grayscale();
```

It makes use of <canvas> so it won't work in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of this being done in reverse (colour to greyscale) with jQuery at:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/hover-over-trick/

I imagine it would be simple enough to reverse this so it went from grey to colour. The code itself looks very simple and elegant.

Comment: Website no longer exists. Therefore this is not an answer. -1

Answer (score 1):

There's a way you can do this with **CSS3** only (so not a jQuery feature in general). It doesn't require any plugins though.

**In CSS add:**

```
.grayscale {
     filter: grayscale( 100% );
}
```

For *Safari* you'll have to use:

```
.grayscale {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale( 100% );
}
```

**In JS use:**

```
$('#myElement').addClass('grayscale');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this trick if your aim is to just make the image gray scale on hover.
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/greyscale-hover-effect-w-css-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I have written a jQuery plugin called [$.greyScale()](http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/2011/08/greyscale-jquery-plugin/) which does this for you. It supports images hosted on another domain by proxying requests as well.

It is just invoked by using

```
$('img').grayScale();
```

Comment: this requires calling a third party service for each image; that service is not workign.

Comment: That's strange it's been working for months. I'll look into it some time.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the ones listed here and they didn't work well (either doing too much like attaching on hover or just not working across browsers or domains). So I whipped one up myself, which is very short and concise: https://github.com/arturnt/jquery.grayscale.js

Comment: this uses the same (broken) service as prydie's library.

Comment: What browser is it broken on?

Comment: wen i looked, it was the web service that was broken.  it was dead.