# jquery grayscale on hover

Tags: jquery

does anyone know whether there is a way to make an image grayscale on hover - other than by creating 2 separate images and altering the src.

thanks

EDIT - SEMI WORKING CODE...:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/pixastic-1.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   var img = $(".test img")

   $('.test').hover(function() { 
       $('img', this).pixastic("desaturate");
   }, function() {
       $(this).html(img);
   });

});
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="test" style="padding:25px; width:200px; background-color:#F96">
  <img class="pic" src="images/home/mainImage/family_woods.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
</div>
```

How can I amend this to work if there is more than one div on the page... like this...

```
<div class="test" style="padding:25px; width:200px; background-color:#F96">
  <img class="pic" src="images/home/mainImage/family_woods.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="test" style="padding:25px; width:200px; background-color:#F96">
  <img class="pic" src="images/home/mainImage/another_image.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474333/jquery-convert-image-to-grayscale

Comment: You may want to check this demo:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/hover-over-trick/

Comment: That's by using by [two images](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/hover-over-trick/sushiandrobots_thumb.gif).

Comment: This uses an additional grayscale image.

Comment: My bad, it clearly uses two source images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these (both use canvas):

1. [javascript image processing library](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/) - desaturate
2. [Desaturate tutorial](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is the one suggested by @Alec, with the `<canvas>` tag. Another one is very tricky and altough it's more cross-browser compatible, I don't know how well it works for larger images. That would be making an AJAX call on hover to a PHP script, sending the image URL as a parameter and having the PHP script return the grayscale image. If you need more details I'll write a short script for you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to jQuery but not ajdusting the actual image source or having 2 images, I think its possible to make an image greyscale within flash with a simple flash movie that handles the mouse over etc.

This looks like good value: http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/as2_luminosity_gray_scale_utility.html

[Not affiliated with this component at all...]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for using "one" image, as you´ll obviously see, its actually two images stuck together, I´m not sure if this helps, hope it does!

BTW no jQuery, just css

HTML

```
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#LinkURL">Leaf</a>
```

CSS:

```
.myButtonLink {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('/path/to/myImage.png') bottom;
    text-indent: -99999px;
}
.myButtonLink:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

source:

http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/pure-css-image-hover/

Comment: @fudgey really nice scripts, love them!! do you know about browser compatibility?

Comment: The Pixastic script shows it's compatibilities on the page I linked. Just so you know, the grey scale/desaturate feature is built into IE : `img.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1)';`

Comment: @fudgey Sorry! you´re completely right, totally missed it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If Pixastic is overkill for you, you can try my simple jQuery plugin: [jquery-grayscale](https://github.com/josefrichter/jquery-grayscale)

You run it like:

```
$('img').grayscale();
```

It makes use of <canvas> so it won't work in older browsers.